# I have an issue in my Like System, like not increase in particular post when i hit like button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

1.my like is not increase in a particular post when  i hit the like button.
2. I am using javascript for on click function to increase the like but it will increase only first post like.
3. when i try to hit another post button than again it will increase the first post like by 1 and so on.
i am unable to find out error in my code where i got wrong.
I just want to when i hit like button of particular post than it will increase that particular post like and store in mysql database with increment manner.

This Is Frontend code

````
          if(userData3.length!=0){
          var i=1;
          userData3.forEach(function(data){
          %>
          <li class="cards_item-li">
            <div class="card-inner">
              <div class="card_image"><img src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/compititionimg/<%=data.file %>"></div>
              <div class="card_content-inner">
                <h2 class="card_title-inner"><%=data.fname %></h2>
               
                <!-- <a class="likeicon" userId="<%= userData3.id %>" onclick="updateLikes()">
                  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true" > 49 </i>
               </a> -->
               <form action="<%=(typeof editData!='undefined')?'/vote-user/'+editData.id:'/edit/'+data.id%>" method="POST">
               

              
               <a href="#" onclick="buttonClick();"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:32px"></i>  </a> 
               <input type="text" class="input-like" id="<%=data.id%>" name="likes" value="<%=data.likes%>"></input>   
                <button  class="btn-like" type="submit" >Like</button>
               </form>

               <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=http://localhost:3000/competition "><i class="fa fa-share-alt"
                  aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:32px"></i></a>

              </div>
              <%  i++; }) %>
              <% } else{ %>

              No Data Found

              <% } %> 

Here Is the Javascript Code
function buttonClick(data) {
      var i = 0;
        i++;
        //i += 1;
        //console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('<%=data.id%>').value = i;
        
    }

Here is the Database Query to store this likes

 app.post('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        var updateData = req.body.likes;
        var sql = `UPDATE finalusers SET likes='${req.body.likes}' WHERE id= '${id}'`;
        mysqlConnection.query(sql, [updateData, id], function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
        });
        res.redirect('/competition');
    });```
please give me the possible solution to find out this problem i am very thankfull to you..
````

Comment: Looks like you need to pass a value to `buttonClick()`: `onclick="buttonClick(data);"`

Comment: i do the same but nothing happen.